# How to intercept requests/responses from Smart Phone while surfing internet?

Tags: penetration-test

I have used Burp Suite Penetration testing tool in my computer to intercept requests.Assume that I am using Smart Phone. So Is it possible to intercept my smart phone requests into my computer?

Comment: Yes you can. But if you are trying to intercept the HTTPS endpoint do kindly keep in mind that you are required to install the certificates of the endpoints to intercept the api calls from your mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a router along the way to redirect traffic from your smart phone to Burp suite on your computer.

For example, you can use IPTables `REDIRECT` target to send it to a local port if you're running an access point on your Burp system to set up a transparent proxy. You can configure a local access point, or connect a router via ethernet and let it provide wireless, getting the traffic naturally through.

Another option if you already have a router setup and don't want to have the router go through your laptop is to [intercept requests and send them over an SSH tunnel](https://systemoverlord.com/blog/2014/07/13/passing-android-traffic-through-burp/).

Of course, you can also get traffic via any other man-in-the-middle technique, like ARP poisoning, it's up to you how you'd like to redirect traffic to the Burp workstation.